# Selected data will trigger the image

Tags: ionic3, angular5, datatrigger, eventtrigger, ion-select

what i want to do is to when i select "studio unit" the image of the studio unit will display only the studio unit ...
 the problem is when i select the studio unit  the image still shows the 3 image  it should show the studio unit iamge...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dh0t.png)

here is my code.
.html

```
<div style="margin-top: -10px"  *ngFor="let house of house_designs; let i - index">
      <div>
    <img src="{{url_asset}}{{house.photo_name}}">
  </div>
  </div>
  <button ion-button full (click)="design()">{{ switchbtn }}</button>
</ion-card>


<form [formGroup]="registerForm"(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<ion-card>
  <ion-item no-lines>
      <ion-label color="primary">House Design:</ion-label>
      <ion-select 
        formControlName="house_design_id"  
        placeholder="Select house design"
         [(ngModel)]="qa_form.house_designs_id">
        <ion-option 
          value="{{house.id}}" 
          *ngFor="let house of house_designs; let i - index"
           name="house_design_id"  
           >{{house.description}}</ion-option>

      </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

Can someone help me tnx...

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit because I don't see anything related to "studio unit" in the code ?

Comment: my bad pls click the image tnx..

Comment: Try the following:

Bind the onChange function to "select" tag and pass the value of url in it on event change. Then you can assign that value to a variable in .ts file which you can use to assign to src in img tag.

Comment: can you show me example @Mu

Comment: You can use it the following way:
    
      
    
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender" (ionChange)="onSelectChange($event)">
            <ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
    
    
    
    then in your page:
    
      
    
        onSelectChange(selectedValue: any) {
           var genderVariable = selectedValue;
          }

Comment: im really sorry  im new in ionic  can you finish he example in .ts file  tnx...

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz for this so I can check the response and help you accordingly ?

Comment: is ok my data are from my localhost... i use commonProvider for the connection and getting data from my localhost   here is  the link of stackblitz:   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c7x7gc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: thank you @Mukul_Vashistha  i solved my problem

Comment: Cool. Meanwhile I gave a working example. Maybe someone else can get some help from it.Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a working example for you.
Check the StackBlitz you had created. I have made changes there for you to understand it.

https://angular-c7x7gc.stackblitz.io

First the .ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
 url:any;
 house_designs:any=[]; 

  ngOnInit(){
    this.house_designs = 

   [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Studio",
      "url": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502759683299-cdcd6974244f?auto=format&fit=crop&w=440&h=220&q=60",

    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "1 BHK",
      "url": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293__340.jpg",
    }
  ]

this.url = this.house_designs[0].url;
  } //ngOnInit

  onSelectChange(selectedValue: any) 
  { 
    this.url = selectedValue; 
  } 
}
```

Now html file:

```
<div>
<img src="{{url}}">
</div>

<select (change)="onSelectChange($event.target.value)" > 
  <option [value]="data.url" *ngFor="let data of house_designs">{{data.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Try changing the dropdown and you'll be able to see that image changes with the value.